# Updating Prometheus metrics Http server: [48] address already in use error

Tags: python, docker, http, prometheus

I'm working on a Dockerized project and monitoring the system state with Prometheus_client package for python.
I've a module named train.py which runs every time a request is sent to the container. in this file I use the logger below to collect model's metrics and expose them

```
class PrometheusLogger(BaseLogger):
def __init__(self):
    self.registry = pc.CollectorRegistry() #pc is for prometheus_client
    self.training_state = pc.Enum('training_state','returns state of training',
                                states=['not started','running','done'], registry=self.registry)
    self.coverage =  pc.Gauge('dataset_coverage','shows the coverage of the datasets',
                            labelnames=['dataset'], registry=self.registry)
    self.diversity = pc.Gauge('model_diversity','shows the diversity parameter', registry=self.registry)
    self.personalization = pc.Gauge('model_personalization','shows the personalization parameter', registry=self.registry)
    self.scores = pc.Gauge('model_scores','shows the scores of the model',
                            labelnames=['name'], registry=self.registry)

def log_metrics(self, metrics):

    self.coverage.labels(dataset='catalog').set(float(metrics['catalog_coverage']))
    self.coverage.labels(dataset='user').set(float(metrics['user_coverage']))
    self.diversity.set(float(metrics['diversity']))
    self.personalization.set(float(metrics['personalization']))
    self.scores.labels(name='rmse').set(float(metrics['test_RMSE']))
    self.scores.labels(name='recall').set(float(metrics['test_recall']))
    self.scores.labels(name='f1').set(float(metrics['test_f1']))
    self.scores.labels(name='ndcg').set(float(metrics['test_nDCG_score']))
    self.scores.labels(name='precision').set(float(metrics['test_precision_k']))

def expose_metrics(self):
    pc.start_http_server(8003, registry=self.registry)
```

and the train function works as follows:

```
def train(model, logger=PrometheusLogger):
model.fit()
metrics = model.get_metrics()
logger.log_metrics(metrics)
logger.expose_metrics()
```

***note that metrics are exposed in port 8003 inside the docker network. another container reaches this port and makes an API to the localhost.***

this code works well for the first time, but when I recall the train function for the second time, I get **Error[48]: Address already in use**.

I've tried many ways like get_pid() and killing it with os.kill but they don't work. what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem happens because  the `start_http_server()` command doesn't automatically update on the port specified and it's actually the `prometheus-client` package problem.
I figured something out and it's not really a **solution** but it works for this scenario.

you can replace the `start_http_server` with this function to answer a limited number of requests if you don't need real time answering and use a `While True` if you need so.

```
import prometheus_client as pc
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

registry = pc.CollectorRegistry()

def expose_metrics(self):
    app = pc.make_wsgi_app(registry=registry)
    httpd = make_server('', 8003, app)
    for _ in range(5): #or While True
        httpd.handle_request()
```